# Template requires newer script versions than project contains

Tags: templates, asp.net-mvc-4, package, nuget, breeze

I try to use the breeze/angular template for MVC 4. However, during start up I get this:

Package installation error

Could not add all required packages to the project. the following packages failed to install from .../asp.net mvc 4\packages

jquery.ui.combined.1.9.2 unable to find version 1.9.2 of package.

Now I see that the folder contains jQuery.UI.Combined.1.8.24, so I was wondering:

1. Is there a way to edit the project so that it (maybe always) uses the latest versions of the packages by default?
2. Should I just press OK and afterwards install jquery.ui through nuget afterwards?
3. Is there a clever way to fix this?

I know there has to be a solution due to the uglyness of getting an error by default when using a custom template. I've been googling my ass off without any results :(

Comment: Are you using a pre-release version when installing from NuGet?

Answer (score 2):

Hope to update the templates soon and get MS to republish. You can't update the template easily yourself.

Fortunately, this particular issue is easy to workaround by adjusting your code to use latest jQuery or rollback to 1.8.x.

Answer (score 1):

I can't use the latest verison of jQuery so I manually updated the jQuery files to 1.9. Also, check your nuget manager for updates. Breeze released 1.3.6 which will update the appropriate dependent project libraries (my jQuery files were untouched).

Answer (score 0):

As of Visual Studio 2012 Update 3, the Breeze/Angular SPA template is totally broken. The jQuery update fix worked with VS2012 Update 2, but some change or another in Update 3 has made VS not play nice with the sample.

It isn't ideal, but given that Update 4 is just around the corner, we might need to hold our breaths in anticipation of a post-Update 4 fix. :(